# How to determine order of occurrence for Tweets (survival analysis?)?

Tags: r, twitter, time-series, survival-analysis

Trying to figure something out for a pet project and is awfully stuck :(

The project centers around order of Tweet occurrences. I collected Tweets on 3 different topics for 2 actors. I want to determine which actor's tweet on each particular topic occurred earlier overall. A friend recommended me look into the package "survival", but I couldn't see how it could work. Any suggestion would be welcome! Thanks so much!

EDIT: Additional information

```
created_at           name
1544469754 chicagotribune
1541550304 chicagotribune 

party     type     topic
M         1        trade
M         1        trade
```

The variable represents in following information

-*created at*: the time the tweet was sent out

-*name*: Twitter account name

-*party*: classification variable of political leaning

-*type*: binary indicator (1 = media type A, 0 = media type B)

-*topic*: the topic the tweet belongs to (3 topics total)

Comment: Please show a small example of the data you're using, it's difficult to understand how you would be applying survival models here without that context.

Comment: @Marius just added! Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a survival analysis problem, you just need to find the earliest timestamp within each topic. I think something like this should work:

```
# Read in example data
df = readr::read_table("created_at           name    party     type     topic
1544469754 chicagotribune    M         1        trade
1541550304 chicagotribune    M         1        trade")

df %>%
    group_by(topic) %>%
    summarise(first_tweeter = name[which.min(created_at)])
```

Comment: Ah thank you! Definitely got narrowed in on some regression method. If I am to do a regresion-form analysis, are there that would be appropriate for this objective?

Comment: @Miko: I'm not seeing where regression would be needed here, it seems all the information you need is known and not randomly varying.